# Flutter global varibals

Tags: flutter, dart

global variables in flutter app don't work in  release mode?My flutter app is working perfectly in debug mode but it's not working release mode.Do I have to wrap global variables inside of class.

My Global variables

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp(
));


int _character=1 ;
bool language=true;
String str = '';
double _strokeSize=0;
double w;
double h;
double f=28;
// double offset=kToolbarHeight;

Color pickerColor = Color(0xff443a49);
Color currentColor = Color(0xff443a49);

Color strokepickerColor = Color(0xff443a49);
Color strokechangeColor = Color(0xff443a49);

ScreenshotController screenshotController = ScreenshotController(); 

//rest of the code

}
```

PS: I'm new to flutter

Comment: How you defined?

Comment: I've updated the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format is,

```
 class GlobalVariable {
   static const int character = 1;
   static const bool status = true;
 }
```

And you should use static keyword, then only it will retain value.

Comment: Those values change by other functions So I can't use `Const` right? How can I use those values inside another class can you explain that if you have a time?